# How to use Row_Number based on Number of Days?

Tags: oracle11g, analytics, row-number

How to group and rank records based on 7 days.

```
Call 1 - 06-Jun-14 16.39.14  Rank 1 
Call 7 - 10-Jun-14 14.28.40  Rank 7
```

After 7 days, whenever the next call date occurs, 
I need to watch the next 7 days and rank accordingly.

```
Call 1 - 27-Jun-14 11.44.35  Rank 1
Call 4 - 03-Jul-14 14.23.39  Rank 4

    CALL_DATE               ROW_NUMBER
06-Jun-14 16.39.14               1
06-Jun-14 17.29.27               2
07-Jun-14 09.13.18               3
07-Jun-14 14.45.52               4
08-Jun-14 13.05.44               5
08-Jun-14 13.14.49               6
10-Jun-14 14.28.40               7
27-Jun-14 11.44.35               1
27-Jun-14 11.46.27               2
27-Jun-14 12.00.21               3
03-Jul-14 14.23.39               4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the day number within the range by using the `first_value()` analytic function and getting the difference; then divide that by seven to get the week number (within the data); and then use that calculate the `row_number()` of each date within its calculated week number.

```
select call_date,
  row_number() over (partition by week_num order by call_date) as row_num
from (
  select call_date,
    ceil((trunc(call_date)
      - trunc(first_value(call_date) over (order by call_date))
      + 1) / 7) as week_num
  from t42
)
order by call_date;
```

Which gives:

```
|                   CALL_DATE | ROW_NUM |
|-----------------------------|---------|
| June, 06 2014 16:39:14+0000 |       1 |
| June, 06 2014 17:29:27+0000 |       2 |
| June, 07 2014 09:13:18+0000 |       3 |
| June, 07 2014 14:45:52+0000 |       4 |
| June, 08 2014 13:05:44+0000 |       5 |
| June, 08 2014 13:14:49+0000 |       6 |
| June, 10 2014 14:28:40+0000 |       7 |
| June, 27 2014 11:44:35+0000 |       1 |
| June, 27 2014 11:46:27+0000 |       2 |
| June, 27 2014 12:00:21+0000 |       3 |
| July, 03 2014 14:23:39+0000 |       4 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8fe3/8) showing some of the intermediate steps and the final result.